# Different reference lines in different panels in an SGPANEL plot in SAS

Tags: reference, sas

I wish to add different horizontal reference lines to each panel in an SGPANEL plot. I currently can only have the one reference line at 0.83

```
proc sgpanel data=TEMP;
panelby AvPatRef / layout=panel columns=3;
format patcorr_order corrformatnum.;
label AvPatRef = 'Average Patient Refusal';
where AvClinRef=0;
refline 0.83 / lineattrs=(thickness=2);
series y=PowerPPLogF x=patcorr_order / legendlabel='PP' markers markerattrs=(symbol=circle) lineattrs=(pattern=1);
series y=PowerITTLogF x=patcorr_order / legendlabel='ITT' markers markerattrs=(symbol=plus) lineattrs=(pattern=1);
series y=PowerSPSLogF x=patcorr_order / legendlabel='2SPS' markers markerattrs=(symbol=diamond) lineattrs=(pattern=1);
series y=PowerSRILogF x=patcorr_order / legendlabel='2SRI' markers markerattrs=(symbol=triangle) lineattrs=(pattern=1);
colaxis discreteorder=unformatted values = (1 to 4 by 1) label='Correlation between baseline CVD risk and refusal probability'; 
rowaxis grid values = (0.4 to 1.0 by 0.02) label='Power';
run;
ods listing close;
```

Thank you for any help.

Best wishes,

Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify variable as your reference line rather than a constant. For example, consider if your panel dataset looks as such:

```
      have
_________________  
x  y  panel_group
1  2  A
3  4  A
5  6  B
7  8  B
```

Let's say for A, you want a reference line at `y=2`, and for B you want a reference line at `y=6`. You can create a new variable holding these values:

```
data want;
    set have;
    if(panel_group = 'A') then ref_val = 2;
       else ref_val = 6;
run;
```

Your dataset now has a different reference value for each panel:

```
     want
_________________________  
x  y  panel_group ref_val
1  2  A           2
3  4  A           2
5  6  B           6
7  8  B           6
```

You can directly reference `ref_val` in your `refline` statement:

```
proc sgpanel data=want;
    panelby panel_group;
    series x = x y = y;
    refline ref_val;
run;
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Yes this solution works perfectly! Thank you and topic can be closed.